# How do I recover a specific file from BACKUP with 16.04.1?

Tags: restore

Recently I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.14 to Ubuntu 16.04.1.
I have used the BACKUP program that was automatically installed. 
Now I have a Backup file:  “.vol1.difftar.gz”. 
How do I recover or restore a specific file? 
I have tried BACKUP, but it seems only willing to restore all “documents”, not just one.

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered that I am able to restore specific files using the Files application. Navigate to the nearest path of the files or folders that you would like to restore and right click. Select 'Restore Missing Files...'. The backup application will scan through all of the backups and provide a list of previous backups.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't seem to have this option. Are you referring to nautilus file browser?

Answer (score 0):

```
cp .vol1.difftar.gz /tmp/backup.gz
cd /tmp/
tar tvfz backup.gz {fileyouwantincluding directory}
```

See if that posts a result. If it does and only shows what you want use

```
tar xvfz backup.gz {fileyouwantincluding directory}
```

---

1st few commands are to make a backup of your backup and to work on that file and not the original.

You can use

```
tar tvfz backup.gz | more
```

to create a list of the contents of the file 1 page at a time to see how it is stored inside that backup.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, "tar xvfz" seems to be a command to view the file content.
The file was created by Linux-UBUNTU Backup program.
Its pathname is: /media/rs/WD USB 2/linux/backups
The file name is:
   duplicity-inc.20160723T215319Z.to.20160729T225757Z.vol1.difftar.gz
I am not certain how is going to unscramble the backup file.
I was able to "cd" to the proper file and use "ls" to view the backup files
   ... but then what?